# Rails trying to fetch data using foreach but getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a blog application .I have a post controller there I have three fields in view title , body and files ..I am passing this files attribute to my model and there I am trying to fetch data using foreach but unable to do so..Getting this error **undefined method [] for ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000035a1970**

[post_Controller.rb]

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user! 

    def index
        @posts = Post.user_post(current_user).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)

    end 

    def new
        @post = Post.new

    end

    def show
        @post = find_params
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        @post.user = current_user


        if @post.save
            Post.upload(params[:post][:files])

            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @post = find_params
    end

    def update
        @post = find_params

        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = find_params
        @post.destroy

        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end

    def find_params
        Post.find(params[:id])
    end


end
 <br>
```

[post.rb]

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 

    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user

    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates :body,  presence: true


    def self.user_post(id)
        role = User.find_role(id)
        if role == 'admin'
            Post.all

        elsif role == 'user'
            Post.where(user_id: id)
        elsif role == 'developer'

        end             
    end
**#########at this point i am getting error#####**
    def self.upload(files)
            k=files[:post][:title]
    end

end
```

[posts/_form.html.erb]

```
<%= form_for @post,html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errors">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %><br>

     <br>
    <%= f.label :files %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :files %><br>


    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already passing `params[:post][:files]` to the `upload` method, so there you don't need `[:post][:files]` anymore. You can use `files` directly:

```
def self.upload(files)
  files.each do |file|
    # Do something with file
  end
end
```

Also, `<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003d40b68>` means that you only have 1 uploaded file, which is not a collection, so you can't use `each` on that. You have to change your form to allow multiple files to be uploaded.

Try this:

```
<%= f.file_field :files, :multiple => true %>
```

Comment: I have already tried this it is giving me error undefined method `each' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003d40b68>

Comment: I need to know how to fetch data using foreach in this case

Comment: what to write inside foreach so that i can fetch data